# Moving QGraphicsItem by using moveBy

Tags: c++, qt

I try to move QGraphicsItem "box" by moveBy(). If I place keyPressEvent in item class - it's work, but if I place this function in mainwindow class and try call moveBy() function through pointer - it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

item.h:

```
#ifndef ITEM_H
#define ITEM_H


#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QKeyEvent>
class item: public QGraphicsItem
{
public:
  //virtual void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);

  item(QGraphicsItem *parent =NULL);
  QRectF boundingRect() const;


  protected:
void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,QWidget *widget);
};

#endif // ITEM_H
```

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "item.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    item *box;
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    virtual void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

item.cpp:

```
#include "item.h"

item::item(QGraphicsItem *parent): QGraphicsItem(parent)
{
    setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable);
}

QRectF item::boundingRect() const
{
    return QRectF(0,0,200,200);

}

void item::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{

    painter->drawPixmap(1,1, QPixmap(":/Graphics/Untitled.png"));
}

/*
void item::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    switch(event->key())
    {
    case Qt::Key_Right:
         moveBy(3,0);
         break;


    case Qt::Key_Left:
         moveBy(-3,0);
         break;


    case Qt::Key_Up:
         moveBy(0,-3);
         break;


     case Qt::Key_Down:
          moveBy(0,3);

      break;

  }


}
*/
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "QGraphicsScene"
#include "QGraphicsView"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene;
    box = new item;
    scene->addItem(box);
    QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView;
    view->setScene(scene);
    view->show();
}
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    switch(event->key())
    {
    case Qt::Key_Right:
         box->moveBy(3,3);
         break;


    case Qt::Key_Left:

         break;


    case Qt::Key_Up:

         break;


     case Qt::Key_Down:


      break;

  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your program even get to the `MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)` when you press the key? Try to debug or put smth like this `qDebug() << "mouse key press in mainwindow";` in your `MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)` method.

Your widget need to grab mouse events to handle this event. I'm pretty sure it's not grubbing a mouse. Another words it's need to be in focus.